# Create order programmatically with UPS shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote, create-order

I'm trying to get available shipping methods and create an order in model.
I have Flatrate and UPS enabled, and see these options in checkout on frontend.

Particularly, list of available methods is formed here:

*app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php*

```
$this->getAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();

$groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Here is my code in Model I'm using to create order:

```
        $email = 'myemail@mail.com';
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
// Start New Sales Order Quote
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
        $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));

// Set Sales Order Quote Currency
        $quote->setCurrency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode());
        try{
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->loadByEmail($email);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            return $error;
        }

// Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

// Set Sales Order Billing Address
        $defaultBillingAdress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(
            [
                'customer_address_id' => $defaultBillingAdress->getEntityId(),
                'prefix' => $defaultBillingAdress->getPrefix(),
                'firstname' => $defaultBillingAdress->getFirstname(),
                'middlename' => $defaultBillingAdress->getMiddlename(),
                'lastname' => $defaultBillingAdress->getLastname(),
                'suffix' => $defaultBillingAdress->getSuffix(),
                'company' => $defaultBillingAdress->getCompany(),
                'street' => [
                    '0' => $defaultBillingAdress->getStreet1(),
                    '1' => $defaultBillingAdress->getStreet2(),
                ],
                'city' => $defaultBillingAdress->getCity(),
                'country_id' => $defaultBillingAdress->getCountryId(),
//                'region' => $defaultBillingAdress->getRegion(),
                'region_id' => $defaultBillingAdress->getRegionId(),
                'postcode' => $defaultBillingAdress->getPostcode(),
                'telephone' => $defaultBillingAdress->getTelephone(),
                'fax' => $defaultBillingAdress->getFax(),
                'vat_id' => $defaultBillingAdress->getVatId(),
            ]
        );

// Set Sales Order Shipping Address
        $defaultShippingAdress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(
            [
                'customer_address_id' => $defaultShippingAdress->getEntityId(),
                'prefix' => $defaultShippingAdress->getPrefix(),
                'firstname' => $defaultShippingAdress->getFirstname(),
                'middlename' => $defaultShippingAdress->getMiddlename(),
                'lastname' => $defaultShippingAdress->getLastname(),
                'suffix' => $defaultShippingAdress->getSuffix(),
                'company' => $defaultShippingAdress->getCompany(),
                'street' => [
                    '0' => $defaultShippingAdress->getStreet1(),
                    '1' => $defaultShippingAdress->getStreet2(),
                ],
                'city' => $defaultShippingAdress->getCity(),
                'country_id' => $defaultShippingAdress->getCountryId(),
//                'region' => $defaultBillingAdress->getRegion(),
                'region_id' => $defaultShippingAdress->getRegionId(),
                'postcode' => $defaultShippingAdress->getPostcode(),
                'telephone' => $defaultShippingAdress->getTelephone(),
                'fax' => $defaultShippingAdress->getFax(),
                'vat_id' => $defaultShippingAdress->getVatId(),
            ]
        );
 $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates();
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
// here things go wrong
$rates = $address->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Only Flatrate in $rates, as opposed to checkout Block.
What Am I doing wrong? Do I miss adding some vital info to quote?

Extra:
Using code from this answer worked a bit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344228/6505678

```
// Update the cart's quote.
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$address->setCountryId($country)
        ->setPostcode($zipcode)
        ->setCollectShippingrates(true);
$cart->save();

// Find if our shipping has been included.
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                 ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

This gave me the right shipping rates: flatrate and UPS. Maybe because I used 'checkout/cart' instead 'sales/quote'. But I couldn't add items and customer to the cart object as I added to quote object.

Is there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the address, I used non US address to test it, and UPS was not available.

Didn't pay attention to this small detail.